# How to wrap every word in spans with PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, explode

I have a some html paragraphs and I want to wrap every word in . Now I have

```
$paragraph = "This is a paragraph.";
$contents = explode(' ', $paragraph);
$i = 0;
$span_content = '';
foreach ($contents as $c){
    $span_content .= '<span>'.$c.'</span> ';
    $i++;
}
$result = $span_content;
```

The above codes work just fine for normal cases, but sometimes the `$paragraph` would contains some html tags, for example

```
$paragraph = "This is an image: <img src='/img.jpeg' /> This is a <a href='/abc.htm'/>Link</a>'";
```

How can I not wrap "words" inside html tag so that the htmnl tags still works but have the other words wrapped in spans? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess you could check every `$c` for the presence of '<' if so do nothing, go the next `$c` and keep doing nothing until you find a part with `>`. After that continue adding `span`. This is a scenario that will easily error though.

Comment: If you are parsing html use an html parser.

Answer (score 2):

Some `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` mechanism?

```
<?php
$content = "This is an image: <img src='/img.jpeg' /> ";
$content .= "This is a <a href='/abc.htm'/>Link</a>";
$regex = '~<[^>]+>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b\w+\b~';

$wrapped_content = preg_replace($regex, "<span>\\0</span>", $content);
echo $wrapped_content;
```

See a demo on <kbd>[ideone.com](http://ideone.com/QHN9aH)</kbd> as well as on <kbd>[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qC9tO2/1)</kbd>.

---

To leave out the `Link` as well, you could go for:

```
(?:<[^>]+>     # same pattern as above
|              # or
(?<=>)\w+(?=<) # lookarounds with a word
)
(*SKIP)(*FAIL) # all of these alternatives shall fail
|
(\b\w+\b)
```

See a demo for this on on <kbd>[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qC9tO2/2)</kbd>.

Comment: Nice one but they both fail if quotes or special chars  are used inside the text. Try with  Thi's and or Thi&#8217;s http://ideone.com/KulE6h

Answer (score 0):

The short version is you really do not want to attempt this.

The longer version: If you are dealing with HTML then you need an HTML parser. [You can't use regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). But where it becomes even more messy is that you are not starting with HTML, but with an HTML fragment (which may, or may not be well-formed. It might work if Hence you need to use an HTML praser to identify the non-HTML extents, separate them out and feed them into a secondary parser (which might well use regexes) for translation, then replace the translted content back into the DOM before serializing the document.